# Voltage is changing. Then why do we use a constant value (if given as battery is 3V)in doing sums.?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

Actually the potential difference changes throughout each part in a circuit and the electrons dont have the same energy (say the battery is 3V) throughout the circuit.then why ,when do we use V=3V as a constant value in proceeding sums...the battery just initially provides the electrons a energy of 3V right?

Answer (score 0):

The voltage from a source is the potential energy given per unit charge. As we pass through the circuit, this energy is converted to other types of energy and the value decreases. This is the principle of the loop law that $ \sum V = 0$ through a closed loop.

If we consider an ideal loop where the resistance in the wires is 0, then we can calculate the drop in voltage across each element in the circuit (bulbs, motors etc.) and use this to determine the voltage at any point.

In reality, some voltage is also lost from dissipation in the wires (converted to thermal energy). In a short circuit (no devices to use the energy) the wires get very hot because the entire potential difference is being dissipated as thermal energy in the wire.

Comment: well, i do not understand how V=0  in a closed loop  containing the source?

Comment: Not V=0 per say but the sum of all sources and elements is 0. Ie, whatever potential is "created" by the source is accompanied by the same reduction from the elements in the circuit. Otherwise, the total potential difference would increase each time you go around and you could create "infinite energy".